# How would you convert keplerian orbital elments into cartesain vectors with quaternions?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements, astrodynamics

Coverting the keplerian elements to cartesain vectors ( posistion and velocity) is relatievly simple by using rotation matrices show in the document here:
https://downloads.rene-schwarz.com/download/M001-Keplerian_Orbit_Elements_to_Cartesian_State_Vectors.pdf

Though I was wondering would I be possible to convert the elements into vectors using quaternions instead of matrix rotation? If so how would you do it?

Comment: different question but potentially helpful to anyone reading up on the subject: [What are quaternions and how are they used to represent spacecraft dynamics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19369/12102)

Comment: doesn't this question just boil down to "how do I transform a vector using a rotation quaternion instead of a rotation matrix?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation method uses a 3-1-3 Euler rotation: rotate by Z, then X, then Z again. For each rotation, one axis (in the new frame) is fixed. A quaternion based rotation requires finding a vector which is immobile between the initial frame and the final frame ([see here](https://eater.net/quaternions) for an excellent visualization and explanation of quaternions). One method to compute the quaternion you need, is to compute the rotation matrix as you normally would and extract the components of the quaternion corresponding to that rotation using the method described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Euler_angles_to_quaternion_conversion) (but ignore the yaw-pitch-roll notation because you're dealing with a 3-1-3 rotation not a 3-2-1 rotation).

The conversion to Keplerian orbital elements to Cartesian orbital element is not typically done using rotation matrices. The reason for this is that it's an incomplete method: it does not work for hyperbolic orbits, and I don't think it works for near circular orbit (because the eccentricity is ill-defined, so the [eccentric anomaly ($E$)](https://nyxspace.com/MathSpec/celestial/orbital_elements/#eccentric-anomaly-ea) will also be ill-defined). Instead, the method used by GMAT and Nyx (and surely others) consists in using the semi-parameter to calculate the radius and velocity vectors, cf. [this explanation](https://nyxspace.com/MathSpec/celestial/orbital_elements/#initialization-methods) and the associated [algorithm](https://nyx-space.gitlab.io/nyx/src/nyx_space/cosmic/orbit.rs.html#261-363).