# How to determine Euler parameters?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements

I have two questions and I can't solve the second one. Here it goes:

**Question 1**

Consider a normalized system of units where µ = 1, Earth radius = 6378.165 km is the
length unity, and T = 806.81 s is the time unit.
Since the position and velocity vector are
given by r = 2.0i + 2.0j + 2.0k and v = -0.4i + 0.2j + 0.4k, respectively, determine the keplerian elements (a, e, i, Ω, ω, M) of the spacecraft orbit, and select the correct option.

My answers are:

- a=4.6;
- e=0.3;
- i=54deg;
- Omega=14.3deg;
- omega=355.4deg;
- M=26.3deg

So the next question (which I don't know what do to) is:

**Question 2.**

Considering the classical Keplerian elements found in Question 8, determine
the Euler parameters.(Beta1, Beta2 and Beta3).

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Why is `spacex` tag added?

Comment: [Related?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54530/how-would-you-convert-keplerian-orbital-elments-into-cartesain-vectors-with-quat) and [Wikipedia?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements#Euler_angle_transformations) are these what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried to add "space" tag.

Comment: Yes it is related but I am not managing to find the answer.